# Python Numpy Reshape Error

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am encountering a strange error while trying to reshape a 3D numpy array.

The array (x) has the shape (6, 10, 300) and I want to reshape it to (6, 3000).

I am using the following code:

```
reshapedArray = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

However, if I turn x into a list, it works:

```
x = x.tolist()
reshapedArray = np.reshape(x, (len(x), len(x[0])*len(x[0][0])))
```

Do you have any idea why this could be?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the code I am running and that produces the error

```
x = np.stack(dataframe.as_matrix(columns=['x']).ravel())

print("OUTPUT:")
print(type(x), x.dtype, x.shape)
print("----------")

x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x[2]))

OUTPUT:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64 (6, 10, 300)
----------

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Could you report : `type(x)` and `x.dtype`?

Comment: type = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

dtype = float64

Comment: What happens if you do `np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], -1))` and if it works what shape does it have?

Comment: I have no issue with the code above. Can you post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the bug?

Comment: np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], -1)) seems to work perfectly, the shape is (6, 3000)

Comment: @MSeifert It indeed works perfectly, any idea why this works and my code above does not?

Comment: Could you share what the following two statements show: `print(x.shape[1]*x.shape[2])` and `print(type(x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))`?

Comment: @MSeifert The first delivers 3000 and the second <class 'int'> (as expected, but this makes the error so strange, it must have something to do with the data inside x)

Comment: Shouldn't that print call be `print(type(x), x.dtype, x.shape)`?

Comment: Wait, the `x` part of `print(type(x), x, x.shape)` prints `float64`? That seems impossible.

Comment: @user2357112 ah no I accidentally deleted the.dtype when I was formatting the code

Comment: Can you `print([type(dim) for dim in x.shape])`?

Comment: This whole situation sounds like there's some crucial discrepancy you haven't noticed between what you're telling us and what you actually ran.

Comment: @user2357112 The output is [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]

Comment: Are you sure the error is occurring at the call of `np.reshape()`?  Include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  It will show the line where the error occurred.

Comment: @user2357112 probably... the only thing I can think of is the way I store the data in the dataframe, but whatever I store in there the output is clearly in the right shape and is ndArray

Comment: Like Warren said: Please include the whole traceback - that would be really interesting. :)

Comment: I can reproduce the error by using a line with a typo: `np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x[2]))`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're right: `np.reshape(x_vector1, (x_vector1.shape[0], x_vector1.shape[1]*x_vector1[2]))`. :)

Comment: `x_vector1[2]` - yup, there's the crucial discrepancy.

Comment: lel... gosh that's embarrassing xD That was indeed the mistake. Have been staring at this screen for too long. Time to go to bed, thanks guys ! You are awesome :D

Comment: I rolled back the question because the traceback contains the "solution" to the puzzle.

Comment: Haha, no problem. If you want: feel free to delete the question. Questions based on typos are unlikely to help future readers and I won't mind if I lose the reputation :)

Comment: No, your help was awesome, you shall keep the reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception should only happen if one element of the second argument for `reshape` isn't an integer, for example:

```
>>> x = np.ones((6, 10, 300))
>>> np.reshape(x, (np.array(x.shape[0], dtype=float), x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

or if it's an `array` (given the edit history: that was what happened in your case):

```
>>> np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x[2]))
#         forgot to access the shape------^^^^
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

However it seems to work with the workaround which also makes it much harder to accidentally mistype something:

```
>>> np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], -1))
```

In case you're wondering about the `-1` the docs explain it:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround! Even if I put int(x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]) it doesn't work and shows a new error:

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @SirTobi, I see that you accepted this answer, but the source of the error is still mysterious.  Any chance you can add a self-contained, runnable example so those of us curious about the problem can try to reproduce it?

Comment: @SirTobi What the ... this is getting really mysterious. How can `x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]` be a NumPy array.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah so I am retrieving the data from a pandas dataframe which I loaded into from an h5 file, I try to create a runnable example.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser So I couldn't reproduce the error with different data, is there way how I can maybe upload my h5 file here?

Comment: I don't know where you can upload it to.  In the meantime, are you really sure that, if you put `print(type(x), x.dtype, x.shape)` immediately before you run the exact line `reshapedArray = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))`, that the output is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64 (6, 10, 300)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, here is the output:

OUTPUT:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64 (6, 10, 300)
---------- I will put an answer for more details

Comment: @SirTobi Just edit the question (don't post an answer if it doesn't actually answer the question).

Comment: @SirTobi You said you have a DataFrame that you store as hdf5 and then load before you do the reshape. In that case just create a dataframe containing only ones (or `random.random(size)`s), save it, load it (like you did before) and do the reshape. If the error happens again include all what you did in the question.