# Concatenate arrays

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, series

I have the following arrays with shape (53248, 1) and (2,1).

```
array1 = data["Acceleration"].values.reshape((-1,1))

array2 = np.matlib.repmat(0,2,1)
```

I want to concatenate them like

```
twf=np.concatenate(array1,array2)
```

Where data["Acceleration"] is a panda series. The reason why I apply the reshape function is to obtain a (53248,1) array shape instead of (53248,).

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Thanks

Comment: what's the error message when you run above code? what is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure the error stems from concatenate and not from reshape? Could you post what you did to make sure about the shape of array1 and array2? Could you try doing the same with a shorter array1 = data["Acceleration"] so it can be more easily debugged?

Comment: Could you give example input (something less than (53248,1) will do) and desired output?

Comment: Read the docs. Pay attention to what arguments `concatenate` requires. It matters!  Be specific about the error line and or traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [220]: array1 = np.ones((5,1)); array2 = np.zeros((2,1))
     ...: 
In [221]: np.concatenate(array1,array2)    
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The first argument to `concatenate` is supposed to be a list of the arrays.  The second, which may also be labeled as `axis`, is the axis on which to join them.  That's supposed to be a scalar.  It's trying convert your `array2` into a scalar, hence the error.

With correct inputs  (the default axis 0 works in this case)

```
In [222]: np.concatenate([array1,array2])
Out[222]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
```

Read the docs

> Docstring:
>
> concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)

Answer (score 0):

You may get it to work using `reshape` with two parameters, as shown in [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
First assign `data["Acceleration"].values` and then work on it.

[Python Numpy Reshape Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927263/python-numpy-reshape-error) may help.

Comment: From the docs: `a.reshape(shape, order='C')`; the `reshape` method accept either a shape tuple or its *args.  IT's fine to suggest that `reshape` was the problem, but you should demonstrate that it can produce the given error message.